# What's the model query of a raw SQL

Tags: django, django-queryset

I working on some kind of pricelist, with prices changing over time.
I'm facing problems with retrieval of latest price for each product.

My models are as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(10000), MaxValueValidator(99999)])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'[{self.id}] {self.name}'


class ProductPart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have a raw SQL variant of this, but can't figure out how to turn it into  a Django Query.
The raw query is:

```sql
select
    pp.id as product_id,
    pp.name as product_name,
    ppp.price as price
from 
    pricelist_Product as pp 
    inner join pricelist_ProductPart as ppp 
    on pp.id=ppp.product_id
where 
    (pp.id, ppp.id) in  
        (
            select 
                pp.product_id, 
                max(pp.id)
            from 
                pricelist_ProductPart as pp 
            group by 
                pp.product_id
        )
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Django actually gives you an option for this:
See [Django Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw).

```
raw()
```

You can use it as such:

```
for i in Product.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM myapp_products"):
    print(i)
```

You could test it out in the Django Shell. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The ORM can do this using Subquery

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

subquery = Subquery(ProductPart.objects.
                    filter(product_id=OuterRef('pk')).
                    order_by('-date_created').  # Can order by date_changed or id if you want
                    values('price')[:1])

Product.objects.annotate(most_recent_price=subquery)
```